# How to send an e-mail using mailgun/mailchimp/etc in an express/node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I want to send automated e-mails like order brief, sign-in e-mail, confirm e-mail, change password e-mail, etc to clients using mailchimp or mailgun or whatever e-mail delivery server because when I used nodemailer, the clients were receiving the e-mails in their spam inbox and sometimes not receiving at all.
Here's the code I used:

automated_emails.js file:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const user = 'xxx'
const pass = 'xxx';

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: { user, pass }
});

const emailPasswordChange = (email, uuid) => {
    ejs.renderFile("./mail/forgot-password.ejs", { uuid }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) return console.log(err)

        let mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxx',
            to: email,
            subject: "Forgot My Password",
            html: data
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) return console.log(error);
        });
    })
}

module.exports.emailPasswordChange = emailPasswordChange;
```

The EJS file is a file that contains the template, and I pass to it the user info like e-mail, name, etc.
They are a bunch of functions I call inside the main index.js file.
How do you suggest me to implement this? Is there a way I can put mailchimp/mailgun/etc's email delivery method inside my nodemailer app?

Comment: The email dropping in the spam box is not directly related to nodemailer, but rather to the reputation of your email, domain and email redirector. Making the correct configuration is minimum for the module to work. I've had problems with email in a spam box with sendgrid and sparkpost. After I started using AWS SES my problems are over.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent moving your email to spam folder be sure that send email (from) is same as userEmail account which used by nodemailer.

I'm using gmail account to send emails using 'nodemailer' and it always success, and here is the code which I use:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var userEmail = 'yourUserName@gmail.com';
var userPassword = 'yourPassword';

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(`smtps://${userEmail}:${userPassword}@smtp.gmail.com`);


// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: userEmail,    // sender address
    to: 'abc1@hotmail.com, abc2@yahoo.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Demo-1', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world from Node.js',       // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world from Node.js</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Comment: This is the form I'm using: `Company Name <info@domain.com>`

Comment: I noticed that some email apps like as outlook spam the emails that its from email domain not same as sender domain, so if the domain of userEmail which you use with 'nodemailer' not same is 'domain.com' for example then I think you will face spam issue.

Comment: I see, and does not using `smtps://${userEmail}:${userPassword}@smtp.gmail.com` have any effect? I used whatever nodemailer docs suggested